# How is the double negation translation similar to CPS in functional programming languages?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, constructive-mathematics

In Wikipedia's [Double-negation translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) article, I found that any formula in classical logic has its double negation as its intuitionist equivalent:

> It is also possible to define φN by prefixing ¬¬ before every
>   subformula of φ, as done by Kolmogorov. Such a translation is the
>   logical counterpart to the call-by-name continuation-passing style
>   translation of functional programming languages along the lines of the
>   Curry–Howard correspondence between proofs and programs.

Could anyone explain how prefixing ¬¬ before every sub formula of a proposition is the logical counter part to call-by-name continuation-passing style? If possible, could you use Python, since I'm not familiar with Scheme and Haskell.

I've done some research into CPS, but I'm not seeing the relationship, apart from the fact that a function $P \to \bot$ doesn't have a return value.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969800/1281433) to [What are the most interesting equivalences arising from the Curry-Howard Isomorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2969140/1281433).

Comment: Some [slides of mine](http://rawgit.com/iblech/talk-constructive-mathematics/master/negneg-translation.pdf) tackle this question. They start with a general introduction to the difference between classical and constructive mathematics and end with specific Haskell code.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt I don't understand the part on interpreting classical logics as defending a proposition *with jumping back the time allowed*. Could you please elaborate? I understand by Curry-Howard correspondence, simply typed $\lambda\mu$-calculus corresponds to classical logic, and roughly speaking, $\mu$ is equivalent to call/cc, something related to jumping back, but I don't understand how this could be understood as defending with jumping backs...

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt (continued) especially, if we consider intuitionistic logic *constructive*, how can we consider classical logic *constructive with jumping back the time allowed*?

Comment: @Yai0Phah: The double negation translation of the law of excluded middle $\varphi\vee\neg\varphi$ stores the current continuation before proceeding to give the bluffed answer $\neg\varphi$ (i.e. $\varphi\Rightarrow\bot$). In case the bluff is called (if evidence for $\varphi$ is presented), the previously-stored continuation is taken and the new answer $\varphi$ is given in place of the old one. This can be regarded as a form of time travel. In this sense we defend the claim $\varphi \vee \neg\varphi$ by means of time travel. Does that make sense? Feel free to ask for further clarification!

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Maybe I am not intelligent enough. It looks like $(A\to\bot)\to\bot$ subsequently going "back" through $(\to\bot)\to\bot$ to $A$. Now I ask a pretty more pragmatic question: do we benefit from this point of view in topoi as you mentioned: sheaf topoi (I would like to first take the special case of Zariski topoi or étale topoi)?

Comment: @Yai0Phah: I don't know an example where that view is useful in the analysis of sheaf toposes. Instead, there a different, more geometric motto, shines: "The double negation of a statement $A$ holds in a sheaf topos if and only if $A$ holds in some dense open subtopos." (For instance, a function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ looks like a single (Dedekind) real number $x$ from the point of view of $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$. This number $x$ is positive iff $f$ is everywhere positive, and it is *not not* positive iff $f$ is positive on a dense open.)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Thanks, I find that the double negation topology is mentioned in the [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+subtopos#double_negation) for general topoi, so seemingly your example is a special case of that. I wanted to see whether the point of view about *jumping back the time* has something to do with this. For me, for the moment, seemingly it is jumping in the "timeline" of the proof (the natural inference), but not directly related to a timeline of the construction inside the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my question is answered in great detail here: http://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html

Comment: Can you add some commentary?  I don't see any mention in that article about the correspondence between double negation and call-by-name CPS.